# Celery SQS + Duplication of tasks + SQS visibility timeout

Tags: python, celery

Most of my Celery tasks have ETA longer then maximal visibility timeout defined by Amazon SQS.

Celery [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html) says:

> This causes problems with ETA/countdown/retry tasks where the time to
>   execute exceeds the visibility timeout; in fact if that happens it
>   will be executed again, and again in a loop.
>
> So you have to increase the visibility timeout to match the time of
>   the longest ETA you’re planning to use.

At the same time it also says that:

> The maximum visibility timeout supported by AWS as of this writing is
>   12 hours (43200 seconds):

What should I do to avoid multiple execution of tasks in my workers if I am using SQS?

Comment: I assume you use acks_late. Perhaps you should have tasks that you expect to run longer than 12 hours to have `acks_late=False`. Did you try that? You do not have to disable acks_late globally (configuration setting), you can simply put this in task annotation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally its not a good idea to have tasks with very long ETAs.

First of all, there is the "visibility_timeout" issue. And you probably dont want a very big visibility timeout because if the worker crashes 1 min before the task is about to run, then the Queue will still wait for the visibility_timeout to finish before sending the task to another worker and, I guess you dont want this to be another 1 month.

From celery docs:

> Note that Celery will redeliver messages at worker shutdown, so having
>   a long visibility timeout will only delay the redelivery of ‘lost’
>   tasks in the event of a power failure or forcefully terminated
>   workers.

And also, SQS allows only so many tasks to be in the list to be ack'ed.

SQS calls these tasks as "Inflight Messages". From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html:

> A message is considered to be in flight after it's received from a
>   queue by a consumer, but not yet deleted from the queue.
>
> For standard queues, there can be a maximum of 120,000 inflight
>   messages per queue. If you reach this limit, Amazon SQS returns the
>   OverLimit error message. To avoid reaching the limit, you should
>   delete messages from the queue after they're processed. You can also
>   increase the number of queues you use to process your messages.
>
> For FIFO queues, there can be a maximum of 20,000 inflight messages
>   per queue. If you reach this limit, Amazon SQS returns no error
>   messages.

I see two possible solutions, you can either use RabbitMQ instead, which doesnt rely on visibility timeouts (there are "RabbitMQ as a service" services if you dont want to manage your own) or change your code to have really small ETAs (best practice)

These are my 2 cents, maybe @asksol can provide some extra insights.

Comment: My previous setup was with visibility timeouts = 5 minutes. After creation of task it was added to queue for execution (lets say with ETA within 6 hours). What happened next surprised me. In logs I saw that new task is added to queue on server every five minutes. And I suspect that all the collected tasks will be executed in 6 hours one by one. That is why I decided to increase visibility timeout.Yes, if worker will crash the redeliverd task will arrive late, but at least there will be 1 task in worker log and not 1000 of them. If I am not thinking in the right way, please correct me.

Comment: It is expected to see new task every ~5 minutes since this was the visibility timeout. This means, if the worker have not started executing this task in 5 mins, then SQS thinks that worker missed that task so SQS will reschedule it to be sent to another worker. Increasing the visiibility timeout is a solution to this issue although it has its own tradeoffs too.

Comment: Here I have two questions. Firstly, using SQS I don't have any other means to control queue except log. So I am assuming that all the tasks which are listed in queue log will be executed. Is it true? Or Celery will check the ID of the task before execution? Second one: now I have only one queue on one server. What will happen if SQS broker will send the same task to the worker on different server? How do you think, will it be executed twice?

Comment: I have not used SQS and havent seen an SQS log so I cannot answer. However if a queue sends a task to two workers, then the task will be executed twice.

Comment: Thank you! I have just created a test for the queue to check if the task will be executed multiple times and it looks like it doesn't matter how many times worker receives the same message.

Comment: Hey, what if I have long running tasks, huge reports which takes around 16 hours to finish. I am using SQS and can't extend the visibilityTimeout beyond 12 hours. What would be the best approach?

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue it depends on what you are trying to achieve.  Maybe you shouldn't use SQS. Maybe you can split the report creation to multiple tasks. Maybe you shouldn't use a task queue but a dedicated ETL script which creates the reports at intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Celery is know for async task scheduler. It really doesn't matter with the count of task. If you send the task to queue, celery will perform the task, until there is an error in the code. You have to check or restrict the duplicate task before sending the task to queue.

Answer (score 0):

In SQS you can change the visibility time out of the message. It is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#changing-message-visibility-timeout). So what you have to do is this, when you are processing the message, you can keep updating the visibility time out regularly and once you are done you can delete the message.

To extend the visibility time out regularly, if you are using some loop, you can keep extending the timeout at the end of each iteration or every x number of iterations depending on the time to complete one iteration. Here is a sample code for doing what I mean.

```
process_message(){
  for(i=0;i++;..){
    .
    .
    .
    if(i%5 == 0){
     extendVisibilityTimeOut(..)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question mentioned that. Problem is that visibility timeout has a limit of 12 hours.

Comment: That is why I mentioned "you can keep updating the visibility time out regularly". So if the code has some for loop, he can keep extending the time out at the end of each iteration.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#configuring-visibility-timeout

"Important
The maximum visibility timeout is 12 hours from the time that Amazon SQS receives the ReceiveMessage request. Extending the visibility timeout does not reset the 12 hour maximum."