# Schedule a task to run at some point in the future (architecture)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, architecture

So we have a Python flask app running making use of Celery and AWS SQS for our async task needs.

One tricky problem that we've been facing recently is creating a task to run in x days, or in 3 hours for example. We've had several needs for something like this.

For now we create events in the database with timestamps that store the time that they should be triggered. Then, we make use of celery beat to run a scheduled task every second to check if there are any events to process (based on the trigger timestamp) and then process them. However, this is querying the database every second for events which we feel could be bettered somehow.

We looked into using the eta parameter in celery (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html) that lets you schedule a task to run in x amount of time. However it seems to be bad practice to have large etas and also AWS SQS has a visibility timeout of about two hours and so anything more than this time would cause a conflict.

I'm scratching my head right now. On the one had this works, and pretty decent in that things have been separated out with SNS, SQS etc. to ensure scaling-tolerance. However, it just doesn't feel write to query the database every second for events to process. Surely there's an easier way or a service provided by Google/AWS to schedule some event (pub/sub) to occur at some time in the future (x hours, minutes etc.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at AWS Step Functions, specifically [Wait State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html)? You might be able to put together a couple of lambda functions with the first one returning a timestamp or the number of seconds to wait to the [Wait State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) and the last one adding the message to SQS after the Wait returns.

Comment: I actually found myself wanting this as a product I could quickly hook up so I built https://posthook.io after not having luck finding something like it.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon's scheduling solution is the use of CloudWatch to trigger events. Those events can be placing a message in an SQS/SNS endpoint, triggering an ECS task, running a Lambda, etc. A lot of folks use the trick of executing a Lambda that then does something else to trigger something in your system. For example, you could trigger a Lambda that pushes a job onto Redis for a Celery worker to pick up.

When creating a Cloudwatch rule, you can specify either a "Rate" (I.e., every 5 minutes), or an arbitrary time in CRON syntax.

So my suggestion for your use case would be to drop a cloudwatch rule that runs at the time your job needs to kick off (or a minute before, depending on how time sensitive you are). That rule would then interact with your application to kick off your job. You'll only pay for the resources when CloudWatch triggers.

Comment: Would this work in a dynamic fashion? E.g. Setting up a cloudwatch rule dynamically that then kicks off the lambda and then deleting the rule. In our use case for example we have users registering and 24hrs after they register, we send them email. Assume five users sign up, the time to send the email for each of them would be different and as a result we'd need flexibility in creating rules in cloudwatch that facilitate for one-off time triggers.

Comment: It definitely would, you would just create and destroy a lot of rules. It does sound a little overkill - I know for emails we use a 'send time' variable in the database and then have a job that polls every minute for items to send for this type of use case. 

If you don't want to do that though, CW will definitely scale to your use case.

Comment: Hey @Patrick, I'm also thinking of using cloudwatch with sqs to fire up tasks in celery worker running in ECS. Can you please suggest what would be the body structure of the message that we'd have to send to SQS?

Comment: @r4v1 - Sorry, I just saw your note in my inbox when looking at something else. SQS as an event *source* can't kick off an ECS task directly. You'd need to process the SQS message (via a lambda, likely) then have that kick off the ECS task. If you're looking at doing something more along the lines of scaling celery workers based on task count in SQS, you'd want to look at scaling rules for an ECS service, and your workers would be members in that service pool.

Answer (score 0):

You could start the job with apply_async, and then use a countdown, like:

xxx.apply_async(..., countdown=TTT)

It is not guaranteed that the job starts exactly at that time, depending on how busy the queue is, but that does not seem to be an issue in your use case.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like `countdown` is just a shortcut to `eta`. The issue with this is we have a long countdown that is longer than the SQS visibility timeout, tasks would be executed again in a loop (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516963/scheduling-celery-tasks-with-large-eta)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Amazon Simple Notification Service? It sounds like it would serve your needs... 
https://aws.amazon.com/sns/

From that page:

> Amazon SNS is a fully managed pub/sub messaging service that makes it easy to decouple and scale microservices, distributed systems, and serverless applications. With SNS, you can use topics to decouple message publishers from subscribers, fan-out messages to multiple recipients at once, and eliminate polling in your applications. SNS supports a variety of subscription types, allowing you to push messages directly to Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) queues, AWS Lambda functions, and HTTP endpoints. AWS services, such as Amazon EC2, Amazon S3 and Amazon CloudWatch, can publish messages to your SNS topics to trigger event-driven computing and workflows. SNS works with SQS to provide a powerful messaging solution for building cloud applications that are fault tolerant and easy to scale.

Comment: We use SNS already, but it does not have the functionality to publish an event to a topic at some point in the future. The key requirement is that we need a task to run at some later point in the future, whether that be a couple of hours or days.

Comment: I see, would you be able to use SNS in combination with normal linux scheduling tools like `at`? Obviously this means that one machine is responsible for scheduling things in the future, but it allows you to remove the once-per-second polling.